# React-testing: unable to detect DatePicker field to initiate change

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have a component which uses the `react-datepicker` package.

I am writing to write a unit test which will edits the dates and thereafter run some logic. However, i am unable to detect the field which for me to change using `userEvent.type()`. I have tried to use getByText, getByRole, getAllByText.

Form.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const Form = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ date1: new Date(), date2: new Date() })
    return (
        <div>
            <Form>
                ...some other fields
                <Form.Group controlId="date1">
                    <Form.Label>Date1</Form.Label>
                    <DatePicker name='date1'selected={data.date1} onChange={(date: Date) => setData({...data, date1: date})}
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="date2">
                    <Form.Label>Date2</Form.Label>
                    <DatePicker name='date2' selected={data.date2} onChange={(date: Date) => setData({...data, date2: date})}
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Form.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('Form Component', () => {
    it('able to change the date', () => {
        const { getByRole } = render(<Form/>)
        const date1Field = getByRole('textbox', { name: /date1/i })

        act(() => userEvent.type(date1Field, '01/01/1990'))

        ... any other action to submit the form
    })
})
```

However, my terminal showed me, which is the same for both date, which it was unable to detect the input field:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role"textbox" and name "/date1/i"

textbox: 

Name=""
<input
    class=''
    name='date1'
    type='text'
    value='05/23/2021'
/>

Name=""
<input
    class=''
    name='date2'
    type='text'
    value='05/23/2021'
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue with the library itself](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/2430) and not being able to pass in any ARIA props into the datepicker in `react-datepicker`.

With using the other library you mentioned `react-day-picker` it is possible to pass props into the input and set aria labels.

```
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';

<DayPickerInput  inputProps={{'aria-label':'Date input 2'}} />
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-day-picker-examplesinput-forked-lj8pp

Comment: Thanks! By any chance do you have any recommended date-picker related libraries which I can use aria props and change its value for unit testing? I have tried couple of other libraries but such as `react-day-picker` and `react-date-picker`, unfortunately it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @MongChangHsi It is possible with `react-day-picker`! I edited my answer so you can see how to implement it. In your case I would `getAllByRole` then run through each one  running `queryByLabelText` to see if it's the one you are looking for.

If you found my answer solves your problem be sure to upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking for a solution which I have adopted Jonathan S. answer,

Form.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DayPickerInput from "react-datepicker/DayPickerInput";
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

const Form = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ date1: new Date(), date2: new Date() })
    return (
        <div>
            <Form>
                ...some other fields
                <Form.Group controlId="date1">
                    <Form.Label>Date1</Form.Label>
                    <DayPickerInput inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'date1' }} value={data.date1} onChange={(date: Date) => setData({...data, date1: date})}/>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="date2">
                    <Form.Label>Date2</Form.Label>
                    <DayPickerInput inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'date2' }} value={data.date2} onChange={(date: Date) => setData({...data, date2: date})}/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Form.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('Form Component', () => {
    it('able to change the date', () => {
        const { getByLabelText } = render(<Form/>)
        let date1Field = getByLabelText('date1') as HTMLInputElement
        
        // Selects your default value of the date field
        date1Field.setSelectRange(0, date1Field.value.length)
        // Replaces it
        userEvent.type(date1Field, '1990-01-01')
       
        ... any other action to submit the form
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

After Trying many solution, and trying and error.

I found a solution that work perfectly fine for me.

```
describe('Date Picker Test', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <DatePikerFunction />
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
    );
  });
  it('Date Picker Change', async () => {
    const datePicker = await wrapper.find('.ant-picker-input input').first();
    await datePicker.simulate('mousedown');

    await waitFor(async () => {
      await wrapper.update();
      const today = await wrapper.find('.ant-picker-cell-today'); // put classname that is used to select the perticular date
      const next = today.nextElementSibling;
      await next.click();
    });
  });
});
```

Here I have find the today's date and then selected tomorrow date.
You can find base on class  or any thing you want and use it.

Hope It will work for you too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might not be needed but in case, you can pass a prop placeholderText='some text' and then get the input using screen.getByPlaceholderText('some text');

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, this perfectly works for me

```
 const startDate = await container.find('.ant-picker-input input').first();
 await startDate.simulate('mousedown');

 await waitFor(async () => {
    await container.update();
    const dateChart = await container.find('.ant-picker-today-btn');
    await dateChart.simulate('click');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works perfectly for me.

**React Code:**

```
 <DatePicker
    id="dob"
    placeholderText='Date of Birth'
    selected={dateofBirth}
    onChange={(date: Date): void => {setDateofBirth(date)}}
    popperProps={{ strategy: 'fixed' }}
    dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
   />
```

**Test Case Code:**

```
it('fireEvent onchange of Date of Birth', async () => {
    const props: LoginProps = {
        dateofBirth: new Date(),
        setDateofBirth: () => { },
        setUniqueRefNumber: () => { },
        showErrorMessage: "yes",
    }
    render(<LoginScreen {...props} />);
    const dob = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Date of Birth')
    fireEvent.change(dob, { target: { value: new Date() } })
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(dob).toBeEnabled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `for` attribute on the `label` tag and then used `getByLabelText`.

```
<div>
   <label for="date-picker">Delivery date:</label>
   <DatePicker
            id="date-picker"
            dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            selected={selectedDate}
            onChange={(date) => {
              ...
            }}
          />
</div>
```

```
it('fireEvent onchange of Date of Birth', async () => {
    const datepicker = screen.getByLabelText("Delivery date:");
    fireEvent.change(datepicker, {
        target: {
          value: "2021-10-01",
        },
      });
}
```